# OpenAL ALUT sound error

Tags: c++, audio, visual-studio-2013, openal

After looking on the internet, I could not find an answer to my issue.
I am creating a game for a university assignment and for extra marks and I have decided to implement sound into my game.

I am using the OpenAL with ALUT .dll's. Here are the errors that I get.

[image: Error List]

Above the error list is me declaring the sound and things I need for sound.

Comment: You could add the code and error directly to the question, so is easier to look at. You could also point to the research you've already done on your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've forgot to link against some libraries.
Those error don't seem to have anything to do with OpenAL though.

Try and find out where the definition of `tle::New3DEngine` is and add this library to your additional dependencies (`Project -> Linker -> Input`). 
You should also add `%(AdditionalDependencies)` which will hopefully get rid of the `GetSystemMetrics` linking error.